# Disabling Table of Contents links in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I'm trying to customize a survey I'm building on Qualtrics so that certain items in the Table of Contents are disabled.  Basically I want you to be able to use the TOC to navigate to previous pages, but not to be able to click on subsequent pages.  This is not something I can customize just using the Qualtrics menu.

I'm trying to add Javascript to each block to enable this feature, but can't get it to work.  I looked into the html elements on my page and under a div labeled "ToC Sidebar", each element of my ToC is there with a unique id (e.g. "FL_34"), and there's an 'onclick' function under this element to go to link's page.  I just want to set this to false. Apologies if this is obvious, I'm new to Qualtrics and Javascript.

Here's what I have right now, any thoughts?

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    $("FL_34").onclick = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct way to disable the onclick.  What you would do is use: `$("FL_34").removeAttribute("onclick");`

However, you really don't want to it do that way at all because you don't want to worry about the specific id's, you don't want to display links that don't work,  and you don't want to add a script to every page.  Instead add this script that hides all the incomplete blocks to the header (Look&Feel/Advanced/Header(edit)/Source):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
  if($('Toc')) {
    $('Toc').select('.Incomplete').invoke('hide');
  }
});
</script>
```

For this to work, you have to set Page Transition to "none".

Comment: Hmm, it certainly looks reasonable.   I tried adding the code and I wasn't able to get it to work.  For some reason it would correctly run on the first page where there are no Complete items, but from the second page onwards it wouldn't work.  Were you able to test this code out? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that for this to work you have to set Page Transition to "none".  I've edited the answer above accordingly.